# Subquery not working with NULL data

Tags: postgresql, subquery, notin, postgresql-9.6

Today I have seen one weird issue in PostgreSQL query. In which I have 2 tables **Products** and **Parameters**.

> **Purpose:**
>
> It's very simple query, I just want to list all products which are not
>   there in parameter table.

**Query:**

```
select 
    id 
from product_proudct
where active=True and 
      id not in 
      (
          select distinct product_id from parameter_view
      )
```

> **Issue:**
>
> It won't list anything if there is null value in
>   parameter table in product_id column. I have verified by just removing null record from the parameter table by adding where clause.
>
> **select distinct product_id from parameter_view where product_id is not null**
>
> And then it's working fine but with null it won't work, it's really
>   strange for me.

I would like to know the reason why subquery not working well with **null** ?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN  (the distinct in the subquery is useless by the way)

Comment: cant reproduce - please share structure and data, I believe you can narrow sample data to two rows - with null and without and put select result to the post?..